# Cannot test app with android 5.1 device(Infinix hot note) on android studio 1.4 and 2.0

Tags: android, adb

I can run my app with emulator perfectly but try to run on device its like the studio is not showing any device in device list (Device Chooser) for selection. Project is run on 
a.  Dell Vostro 3000 series laptop running window 10

The following process have been done:
1.  Enabled used debugging on device
2.  Android USD driver in SDK manager -> INSTALLED
3.  App manifest file (debugable=true) and build.gradle setting done
4.  Instruction on developer using device followed

6. disable driver signature enforcement
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zLLY.png)
   [trying to install driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKtGP.png)

Answer (score 1):

I installed this application PdaNet, restarted my laptop and now android studio detects my android 5.1 infinix hot note.Any  time i start android studio PdaNet is runned so dat the infinix phone is detected. Its really awesome. You can get PdaNet from http://pdanet.co/a/ Hope it works for you